# Why does wxPython cut some parts of my layout / window?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a *wyPython* application that renders a GUI derived from `wx.Frame`. That GUI window consists of a scroll pane to render images (`wx.StaticBitmap`), a panel below that for some input lines, and another panel for some information or text lines. Everything works fine, here is a screenshot of how the window should look like (as from my minimal working example, see below):

[image]

Note in particular the bottom of the window, where you can find the four text lines - everything as expected. However, when I now set the minimum height for the bitmap panel, then the lower part of the text panel below gets cut or clipped, like this:

[image]

When I set the variable `MIN_IMAGE_SCROLL_AREA_HEIGHT` to `600` then it works fine, but when set to `700` I encounter this problematic behaviour. But I don't see the problem in my code, can you help me?

Here is a fully working minimal example:

```py
import wx
import wx.grid
import wx.lib.intctrl
import wx.lib.inspection
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel


class TestApp(wx.Frame):
    DEF_IMAGE_SIZE = 800
    MIN_IMAGE_SCROLL_AREA_HEIGHT = 700  # with 600 it works correctly

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(None, title="wxPython Test", style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        self.init_panel()
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def init_panel(self):
        self.main_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.bitmaps_panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.main_panel)
        self.bitmaps_panel.SetMinSize((-1, self.MIN_IMAGE_SCROLL_AREA_HEIGHT))
        self.bitmaps_panel.SetBackgroundColour("black")

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.main_panel.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
        self.bitmaps_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.bitmaps_panel.SetSizer(self.bitmaps_sizer)

        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(wx.Image(self.DEF_IMAGE_SIZE, self.DEF_IMAGE_SIZE))
        self.bitmaps_sizer.Add(wx.StaticBitmap(self.bitmaps_panel, wx.ID_ANY, bitmap))
        self.bitmaps_sizer.Fit(self)

        self.main_sizer.Add(self.bitmaps_panel, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(5)
        self.main_sizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.main_panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(self.DEF_IMAGE_SIZE + 30, 1)))
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(10)

        self.input_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.input_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.input_panel.SetSizer(self.input_sizer)
        self.input_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.input_panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Input Line"), 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.main_sizer.Add(self.input_panel, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(10)
        self.main_sizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.main_panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(self.DEF_IMAGE_SIZE + 30, 1)))
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(10)

        self.stats_panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.stats_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.stats_panel.SetSizer(self.stats_sizer)
        self.stats_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.stats_panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Test Line 1"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.stats_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.stats_panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Test Line 2"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.stats_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.stats_panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Test Line 3"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.stats_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.stats_panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Test Line 4"), 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.main_sizer.Add(self.stats_panel, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(10)
        self.main_sizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.main_panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(self.DEF_IMAGE_SIZE + 30, 1)))
        self.main_sizer.AddSpacer(1)

        self.main_sizer.Fit(self)
        self.main_panel.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wxapp = wx.App()
    app = TestApp()
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing the Layout and Fit seems to fix it under Linux with wxPython 4.1.0
Replacing

```
self.main_sizer.Fit(self)
self.main_panel.Layout()
```

with:

```
self.main_panel.Layout()
self.main_panel.Fit()
```

seems to do the job.

[image]

Note: you are using sizers at the panel level but not at the frame level i.e. `self`, this in itself will cause a problem, when it comes to `fitting` within the window (frame).

Comment: Thanks, after upgrading to `wxPython 4.1.0` and changing my code as you suggest it works now for me. For the records (I didn't see that first): You are calling the `Fit()` function on the `main_panel`, not the `main_sizer` as in my code. I am doing both now and that works fine. One more question though: You also write that I might want to consider using sizers for the frame itself (`self`), could you please be so kind and elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Perhaps it's a oddity of my own but even in a multi-panel environment like this one, I tend to tie it all back to a `Master` sizer, which is assigned to `self`. In the same way that you have rolled it all up into a `main_sizer`, that in this instance is assigned to the main panel. The point being that the main panel still has to reside within the frame, in the same way that the sub-panels reside within the main-panel.